# Change image name and update into same table using mysql query

Tags: mysql

I want to change image name in table like below.

image name : test.png

replace with : test_E.png

I want _E at end of all image name in table using mysql query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use replace function

```
update <table>
set image=replace(image,'.png','_E.png')
```

you could use this, if the image extension is not same in the table

```
   update <table>
     set image=concat(substring(image,1,locate('.',image)-1),'_E',
                 substring(image,locate('.',image),lenght(image)))
```

Comment: typo in replcae ;) that should be REPLACE

Comment: In MySQL length('string') returns length in bytes - we have to be careful while using multibyte chars/internationalization. There is a string function called char_length('string') that returns number of characters which is localization safe

Answer (score 0):

You can use string functions of MySQL query:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET IMAGE_NAME = CONCAT(SUBSTR(IMAGE_NAME,(CHAR_LENGTH(IMAGE_NAME) - 4)),
'_E' , SUBSTR(IMAGE_NAME, -4)) WHERE ID = <put record id>;
```

`SUBSTR(IMAGE_NAME,(CHAR_LENGTH(IMAGE_NAME)-4))` would return name of file - assuming extension is of 3 chars. For 'test.png' above function would remove '.png' and function would return 'test'

`SUBSTR(IMAGE_NAME, -4)` would return last four chars of string - so 'test.png' would return '.png'

using concat you can concat 'test', '_E' and '.png' - returning 'test_E.png'

Please refer to string functions reference of MySQL for further use

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html